# Please how can i get current html page title and pass to submit form

Tags: html

Pls i would want the script to be in javascript only.
I would want to get the page title and pass it to a submit form, so when its being submited, i can see the actual page name user sent the request from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this 
**Using Jquery**

```
$(document).find("title").text();
```

Or in **generic** way

```
var title = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;
```

**Update**

you can append item in form like this

```
function AppendHiddenField(theForm) {
    // Create a hidden input element, and append it to the form:
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'hidden';
    input.name ='PageTitle';
    var Pagetitle = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;
    input.value = Pagetitle;
    theForm.appendChild(input);
}
```

you can use this function to append a hidden field to the form before submitting it.

**Update** Here is working code
you need to assign your form an id.

**JS**

```
window.onload = function(){
var input =document.createElement('input');
var frm = document.getElementById("myform");
input.type = 'hidden';
input.name ='PageTitle';
input.value = document.title;
frm.appendChild(input);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="myform" method="submit" action="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://lmn.9nty.com/?testlink=www.learnmoreng.com/site_rp.xhtml"> <input type="text" name="l" value=":getid-url:"
maxlength="20" size="9"/>
<input type="submit" value="Share" style="background-color:#f3f4f5;padding:3;color:#339900;font-weight:italic"/></form>
```

Comment: I need it in javascript, is that possible?

Through the generic way, how can i get the title down to the form, pls?

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can use this function before submitting the form

Comment: I have tried with what you  gave me, still doesnt work, here is my code: learnmoreng.com/forum2_theme_111582926.xhtml?tema=3 
I  would love if u can edit the  errors and post the full  working code, thank you.